# registration fails due to old version - YOWSUP

Tags: yowsup

This may sound old...

While registering my number using yowsup-cli, I'm getting the following error:

```
    INFO:yowsup.common.http.warequest:{"login":"************","status":"fail","reason":"old_version"}

status: fail
reason: old_version
login: ************
```

That's because I have

```
yowsup-cli v2.0.15
yowsup 2.5.0
```

I tried out all the solutions suggested out here... like,
updating
upgrading through pip
upgrading through GitHub
reinstalling
and tried out yowsup tutorials...

Is there any other option to solve this issue?
or what may the problem here??

Answer (score 2):

Working in my case :

Edit /yowsup/env/env_android.py

```
_KEY = "eQV5aq/Cg63Gsq1sshN9T3gh+UUp0wIw0xgHYT1bnCjEqOJQKCRrWxdAe2yvsDeCJL+Y4G3PRD2HUF7oUgiGo8vGlNJOaux26k+A2F3hj8A="

_MD5_CLASSES = "ry9Xz6kVioQctwA3G9z62Q=="

_VERSION = "2.12.556"
_OS_NAME = "Android"
_OS_VERSION = "4.3"
_DEVICE_NAME = "armani"
_MANUFACTURER = "Xiaomi"
_BUILD_VERSION = "JLS36C"
_AXOLOTL = True
```

then compile again

After execute this command :

```
./yowsup-cli registration -E android --requestcode sms --phone 91xxxxxxxxx --cc 91 --mcc 232 --mnc 10
```

Or

You may also set default environment yowsup simulates on below file :

```
cat yowsup/env/env.py
...
DEFAULT = "android"
...
```

You will get the sms/voice !

Comment: What about the `_KEY` field?

Comment: thank you, but it's still not working to me (nevermind, I give up with yowsup ftm).

Comment: @Linuslabo have you latest clone of `yowsup` ?  here again updated my answer, please verify your config, still error then show me full error message.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to update the `/env/env_android.py` file with _MD5_CLASSES and _VERSION variables. Please follow the link.
[How to fix old version error while registration](https://iamjagjeetubhi.wordpress.com/2017/09/21/how-to-use-yowsup-the-python-whatsapp-library-in-ubuntu/#step2)

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same issue for a lot of time.

Finally tried this with the last, last, version and key:

https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/pull/1716/commits/5782facf63751b135b55a50c42709291a4768302

Let us know.
Jorge B

Comment: pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'yowsup-cli'      I'm getting this error... but I have already installed yowsup-cli. how to overcome this?